Import products to magento, tax_class_id problem
I tried to import products to magento 2 but I got error:"Value for 'tax_class_id' attribute contains incorrect value"
So where to find tax_class_id ? I tried  Tax Class from products but it does not work. Seems like  Tax Class and  Tax Class ID is different.,
Strange is that if I download sample data there is only tax_class_name (Taxable Goods) but not tax_class_id and still system wont let me import anything without tax_class_id
Thanks

I've got the same issue. Did you manage to fix this in the meantime?
